# Oracle Apex 19.1 (how to add, edit, delete data through a form)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm new to oracle apex so this might be simple.

I have an application that i'm currently building. I have an 'employee' table in the SQL workshop. When i attempt to create a form linked to the table there is no option to edit, delete, or add entries into the table ,once the form is completed?

This is essentially what i need help with. I need to be able to manipulate the 'employee' table through the form created rather than through anything within the sql workshop. Just for context i am not the workspace admin, however i am a contributor.

I would appreciate if anyone could provide me with a quick step by step guide into creating this desired form accurately.

Comment: yaya30001996, just a heads up, if someone's answer worked for you then you should accept it. This lets future viewers know it's a proper solution and gives the person that answered it some points. :) See this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to create (using the Wizard, of course) **Report with Form on Table**. It will create

- interactive report you'd use to *view* data stored in that table
- form which will be used to insert/update/delete data

  - the same form will be called when you push

    - the "Create" button in order to create new rows, or
    - icon at the beginning of every line in the report in order to update/delete rows

This combination (report + form) works nicely *for ages*, so ... try it. I hope you'll find it useful.